# CPLEX Sum in Sum

Tags: optimization, sum, linear-programming, cplex

I am new to **CPLEX** and I would like to ask how can I code the following objective function in CPLEX. I have tried few ways but none seemed to work.

[image: 1]

Where N and S are indexes, WP and WL are variables and LCP and LCP are model parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with

```
int N=2;
int S=3;

int LCP[i in 1..S]=i;
int LCL[i in 1..S]=i*2;

dvar int+ WP[1..N][1..S];
dvar int+ WL[1..N][1..S];

minimize sum(n in 1..N,s in 1..S) (WP[n,s]*LCP[s]+WL[n,s]*LCL[s]);
subject to
{

}
```